# Android remove RecyclerView refresh animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Im using FirestorePagingAdapter to populate RecyclerView with data from Firestore query. Every time user refreshes data with SwipeRefreshLayout or use simple search function, RecyclerView blinks to update content. I wish I could remove whose blinks so that already loaded/cached data would remain intact.

I tried to remove RecyclerView animation, but it just speeds up those blinks. I guess I should implement DataSnapshotListener with onDataSetChanged() to listen for updates and prevent adapter from updating view. But I cant find appropriate solution.

I refresh content this way:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                Adapter.refresh();
            }
        });
```

And I use query update to implement search function:

```
private void listSearch (String searchText) {
        String newSearch = searchText.toLowerCase();
        Query searchQuery = Reference.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("title", newSearch);
        FirestorePagingOptions<Adapter> searchOptions = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Adapter>().setLifecycleOwner(this).setQuery(searchQuery, pagerConfig, Adapter.class).build();
        Adapter.updateOptions(searchOptions);
    }
```

**Edit:** I've tried to use my document IDs from Firestore inside getItemId(). But with no success. Made a new field with long attribute in my database. And tried to use it. Again no success. (

```
            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getItem(position);
            assert snapshot != null;
            Long order = snapshot.getLong("order");
            return order;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blinking effect usually happens when you are not using `StableId`s and therefore the `RecyclerView` is will try to use a new `ViewHolder` each time you do a refresh.

To resolve that, in your `Adapter` class, use `setHasStableIds(true)` and then make sure you override `getItemId(int position)` to something meaningful like the `id` of the items being searched or something similar. Never return the position itself as the Id.

Comment: I got stuck here. Ive made a new field in my model class and I pass document Ids from firebase there. But I cant realize how to hook it to getItemId(). I've updated my question. Maybe somebody can provide a bit of clarification.